# How to get Containers to fill available vertical space in a Row?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

can anyone help me out?

I'm struggling to figure out how I can get the coloured containers to extend to match the height of the tallest one in their row.

Currently they have no fixed height/width and are wrapped in Expanded widgets to get their dynamic size.

I'd like to keep their responsive sizes if possible. I already have a method in place to switch to a Column instead of a Row once the screen is small enough. Once in a Column I can use `width: double.infinity` because there is no horizontal scroll..

[image: Row with Containers]

This is an example of the code used (sorry there's so much!):

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Scrollbar(
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverNavBar(),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                [
                  Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: _homePageContent(),
                     );
                  Footer()
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
_homePageContent() {
  return <Widget>[
    _HomePageInfoBox(
      backgroundColor: accentColor,
      title: 'THIS IS A TITLE',
      body:
          'Lorem ipsum...',
    ),
    _HomePageInfoBox(
      backgroundColor: primaryColorDark,
      title: 'THIS IS A TITLE',
      body:
          'Lorem ipsum....',
    ),
    _HomePageInfoBox(
      backgroundColor: primaryColor,
      title: 'THIS IS A TITLE',
      body:
          'Lorem ipsum...',
    ),
  ];
}
```

```
class _HomePageInfoBox extends StatelessWidget {
  const _HomePageInfoBox({
    Key key,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.body,
    @required this.backgroundColor,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  final String body;
  final Color backgroundColor;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      Container(
      color: backgroundColor,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              title,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: primaryTextColor,
                  fontSize: 25,
                  fontFamily: 'CoffeeAndTea'),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            Text(
              body,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: primaryTextColor,
                  fontSize: 24,
                  height: 1.4,
                  fontFamily: 'ElegantSans'),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Text(
              "Let's Go!",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white, fontFamily: 'CreamCake', fontSize: 30),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ],
        ),
       ),
     ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi mate, no sadly not. I got a render box error with no max height. Did it work for you or have you got any other ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To adjust row items height to biggest one wrap row of items with `IntrinsicHeight` widget:

```dart
  IntrinsicHeight(
    child:Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: _homePageContent(),
    ),
  ),
```

[Here](https://dartpad.dev/31846178dc9751a6b0056d374e45479f) is dartpad demo.

Comment: It should be noted that the Flutter documentation team discourages the use of `IntrinsicWidth` and `IntrinsicHeight` because it introduces some fairly hefty performance hits, seeing as it effectively has to layout its child at least 2*N times and as many as N² times (where N is the depth of the tree from that point down) during a single build run. Essentially, only use it if you're confident that it's the only practical way to achieve a particular layout.

Comment: @Abion47 Why "layout its child at least 2*N times"? Intrinsic is a speculative pass. Layout happens once. When I say "layout" I mean the calculation. Bubbling back up cant be considered an extra step right?

Comment: @BossMan That's just what it says in the documentation, so I'm not sure. If I had to guess, I'd say `Intrinsic` renders the entire tree as normal in the speculative pass, then performs an additional layout based on the speculative render. If you have multiple `Intrinsic`s, this would mean you have N widgets being rendered M times where N is the height of the widget tree and M is the number of speculative passes plus the final pass, so the number of widgets being rendered becomes M*N which would approach N² as M approaches N.

Comment: But like I said, that's just my guess. But at any rate, its what the documentation says, so I have no reason to doubt it. Which is why if there is any other more deterministic way to perform layout you want to achieve rather than depending on `Intrinsic`, that is the better approach.

Comment: @Abion47 intrinsic is just a calculation of a could-be widget size. `Intrinsic` WIDGETS dont render in speculative pass neither in layout. Rendering happens after. I understand why the document says "O(N²) in depth of the tree". My question was more about why you said "layout its child at least 2*N times".

Comment: I dont think children are laid out 2*N times. They are laid out once. It's the **calculation** that happens twice.

Comment: @BossMan First of all, a "calculation of a could-be widget size" is the literal definition of a **speculative** layout pass - pretend to layout the widgets, then see how much space they take up and pass the result back to the real layout pass. Second, my explanation of _why_ the widgets lay out 2*N times is speculative, but the fact that it does is not. When you say they don't, you aren't arguing with me, you are arguing with the Flutter development team and their documentation.

Comment: Verbatim from the documentation: "This class is relatively expensive, because it adds a speculative layout pass before the final layout phase. Avoid using it where possible. In the worst case, this widget can result in a layout that is O(N²) in the depth of the tree."

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your body `Text` widget with a `Expanded`. Since your parent `Widget` is `Column`, `Expanded` will give that widget all available vertical space.

```
Expanded(
  child: Text(
     body,
     style: TextStyle(
       color: primaryTextColor,
       fontSize: 24,
       height: 1.4,
       fontFamily: 'ElegantSans'),
 ),
),
```

Or you can do it to the `"Let's Go!"` `Text` widget to avoid that one going all the way to down of screen.

Updated:

Note that you can use `IntrinsicHeight` as other answer mentioned but I always trying to avoid using it because that class is relatively expensive. Here is why from [doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html):

> This class is relatively expensive, because it adds a speculative
>   layout pass before the final layout phase. Avoid using it where
>   possible. In the worst case, this widget can result in a layout that
>   is O(N²) in the depth of the tree.